# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The data is invalid.' in WPF application with Azure authentication

Tags: c#, cryptography

So I have this application, where I have added authentication using Azure AD. For this I have made a class called AuthenticationManager:

```
internal class AuthenticationManager
{
    private readonly string _clientId;
    private readonly string _tenantId;
    private readonly string _redirectUri;
    private string _authToken;
    private DateTimeOffset _tokenExpirationTime;
    private TimeSpan _authenticationDuration;

    public AuthenticationManager()
    {
        _clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        _tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantId"];
        _redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];
        _authenticationDuration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    }

    public bool IsUserAuthenticated()
    {
        _authToken = SecureStorage.RetrieveAccessToken();
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_authToken) && DateTime.UtcNow < _tokenExpirationTime;
    }

    public async Task<string> AuthenticateUser()
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_authToken) || DateTime.UtcNow >= _tokenExpirationTime)
            {
                var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientId)
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_tenantId}")
                .WithRedirectUri(_redirectUri)
                .Build();

                var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

                var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

                _authToken = authResult.AccessToken;
                _tokenExpirationTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(_authenticationDuration);

                SecureStorage.StoreAccessToken(_authToken);

                return authResult.AccessToken;
            }
            else
            {
                return _authToken;
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }            
    }     
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here, is that if the user has already authenticated once within 1 day, then it should skip the authentication.

I then made a nested class called SecureStorage, where I am trying to encrypt the data from the token I acquire and store it. At next run-time, it then tries to decrypt the data and return that as the token:

```
internal static class SecureStorage
{
    private const string _resourceName = "CDBManagerAccessToken";
    private static readonly object _lockObject = new object();

    public static void StoreAccessToken(string accessToken)
    {
        byte[] entropy = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accessToken);
        byte[] encryptedData = ProtectedData.Protect(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(accessToken), entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            if (config.AppSettings.Settings[_resourceName] == null)
            {
                config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(_resourceName, Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData));
            }
            else
            {
                config.AppSettings.Settings[_resourceName].Value = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
            }

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }  
    }

    public static string RetrieveAccessToken()
    {
        byte[] entropy = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_resourceName);

        lock(_lockObject)
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            string encryptedData = config.AppSettings.Settings[_resourceName]?.Value;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedData))
                return null;

            byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData);
            byte[] decryptedData = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedBytes, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedData);
        }   
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I keep getting an `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The data is invalid.'` at the `byte[] decryptedData = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedBytes, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);` in the `SecureStorage.RetrieveAccessToken()`

It's the first time I am really trying to fiddle around with encrypted data and I haven't been able to crack the case as to why it's happening.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're inputting different values for the `optionalEntropy` parameters to `Protect` and `Unprotect`. `byte[] entropy = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accessToken);` when protecting and `byte[] entropy = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_resourceName);` when unprotecting.

Comment: But the accessToken is being stored in the appsettings under the _resourceName:    `config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(_resourceName, Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData));` so it should be the same data no?